# Unable to toggle/click/hover answers

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a template and in that I have 3 questions and answers which I an trying to hide and only after using toggle/hover or click, a user can see the answers.
Now I am able to hide the answers but unable to display them using any of 3 options.
the code is as:

```
  <div class="main">
            <h1>A One Page FAQ</h1>
            <h2>I've heard that JavaScript is the long-lost fountain of youth. Is this true?</h2>
            <div class="answers">
                <p>Why, yes it is! Studies prove that learning JavaScript freshens the mind and extends life span by several hundred years. (Note: some scientists disagree with these claims.) </p>
            </div>
            <h2>Can JavaScript really solve all of my problems?</h2>
            <div class="answers">
                <p>Why, yes it can! It's the most versatile programming language ever created and is trained to provide financial management advice, life-saving CPR, and even to take care of household pets.</p>
            </div>
            <h2>Is there nothing JavaScript <i>can&#8217;t</i> do?</h2>
            <div class="answers">
                <p>Why, no there isn&#8217;t! It&#8217;s even able to write its own public relations-oriented Frequently Asked Questions pages. Now that&#8217;s one smart programming language!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and the script is :

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.answers').hide();
        $('.main h2').click(
            function () {
                $('.answers').show();
            },
            function(){
           $('.answers').hide();
            }
        );
        });
```

don't know where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As zzzzBov said, toggle is a better option. I've mocked it up here:

http://jsfiddle.net/tjtp9jf5/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.main h2').click(function () {
         $(this).next().toggle();
     });
 });
```

You can use this and it should work.
The code shows the corresponding answer when a question is clicked. If you want all of the answers to show up, use:

```
$(".answers").toggle();
```

instead of

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```

Comment: superbbb answer..
but instead of main(), can't I use toggle function so that I don't have to click on question everytime..and  i am using jquery-1.11.1.min version.

Answer (score 1):

[`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) takes one event handler. You should be using [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) if you're using an older version of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/uzgvxhj0/

Otherwise, just use the [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method on `$('.answers')`:

```
$('.main h2').click(function () {
    $('.answers').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k13bnmdq/

---

Note, the script as you've provided will toggle the display of *all* answers, rather than the ones immediately after the heading.

Comment: but instead of calling click() on h2, I want to do toggle so that i don't have to click on questions. and i am using jquery 1.11.1.min

Comment: @MunishGupta, are you looking for something along the lines of [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/eafshL3v/)?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using CSS classes as opposed to the jQuery show/hide function. This way we have more control over what we want to do with the style.

```js
$('.main h2').on('click',function(){
  $(this).next('.answers').toggleClass('answers-revealed');
})
```

```css
.answers {
  display: none;  
}
.answers-revealed {
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
            <h1>A One Page FAQ</h1>
            <h2>I've heard that JavaScript is the long-lost fountain of youth. Is this true?</h2>
            <div class="answers">
                <p>Why, yes it is! Studies prove that learning JavaScript freshens the mind and extends life span by several hundred years. (Note: some scientists disagree with these claims.) </p>
            </div>
            <h2>Can JavaScript really solve all of my problems?</h2>
            <div class="answers">
                <p>Why, yes it can! It's the most versatile programming language ever created and is trained to provide financial management advice, life-saving CPR, and even to take care of household pets.</p>
            </div>
            <h2>Is there nothing JavaScript <i>can&#8217;t</i> do?</h2>
            <div class="answers">
                <p>Why, no there isn&#8217;t! It&#8217;s even able to write its own public relations-oriented Frequently Asked Questions pages. Now that&#8217;s one smart programming language!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```